# Candidates for combinatorial one-way permutation

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, permutations

It is known that (worst-case) one-way permutations exist if and only if $P\ne UP \cap coUP$. Almost all candidates that I know are based on hard number theortic problems. I came across a combinatorial construction of [one-way permutations based on quasigroup string transformations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/352.pdf).

> What other combinatorial candidates for one-way permutations are known?

Comment: Are you interested in [trapdoor permutation families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function#Definition) over products of fixed-size $\hspace{1.81 in}$ (at most 8 elements) finite fields? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer No, just basic worst-case one-way permutation would be fine.

Comment: Hmm, that's harder. ​ ​

Comment: Relevant: eprint 2015/752: http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/752

Comment: Is there a specific use-case you have in mind for one-way permutations? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes. To understand how to convert worst-case hardness into average-case hardness.